# How to get file info with directory_map codeigniter

Tags: php

I am using directory_map to get the images inside the folder. But i want to show the images by date modified (in descending order) below is my code

```
$dir = realpath(FCPATH) . "/assets/images/articles/";
$map = directory_map($dir);
```

Is there any way to show files in descending order or to get the file info?

Comment: As it currently stands, your question contains a lot of irrelevant code. Please reduce it to the smallest program that still reproduces the issue and ask about _that_.

Comment: After submittion it displays mail.php page with "error" written on it insted of "Thank You" Message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

few variables r missing in ur code..

```
    <?php
   //these r missing into ur code
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];

    $remarks = $_POST['remarks'];

    $to = "abcd@abcd.com";

    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see you defining `$to` anywhere in those lines you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Could you mention the error please ...?
Also there is no $to variable defined in the code in mail.php